# Problems maintaining connection to bluetooth headset in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, audio, bluetooth, headset

Until a few days ago I was using a bluetooth headset (Plantronics Voyager PLT510) regularly and without issue in Windows 7, primarily for making calls in Google Talk. I then upgraded to Windows 8 and am now stuck with a problem maintaining connectivity between my laptop and the headset.

The laptop recognizes the headset and was paired no problem. It also recognizes when the headset is on and when it should be receiving audio (it is my default audio device as well as the default microphone). So, I switch the headset on and get the initial *beep* letting me know that it's connected to the laptop. I then try to place a call or listen to some audio at which point I should get a slightly different *beep-beep-beep* when it "becomes active" and audio is ready to start coming through. At this point it tends to go crazy and just starts beeping repeatedly, almost as if it is continually trying to establish communication over and over. Often, it just becomes silent and there is no audio nor microphone.

Things I have tried:

- Uninstalling the old bluetooth driver and using the latest Win8 bluetooth driver instead
- Upgrading to latest Win8 bluetooth and audio driver from laptop manufacturer
- Unpairing and re-pairing the headset with the laptop
- Testing with different browsers (for the GTalk) and different audio sources
- Verified strong signal between the two, 5 out of 5 bars

Any suggestions? Anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: I've had nothing but trouble from Dell's Bluetooth hardware for years. I finally bought a tiny Bluetooth usb dongle and disabled Dell's, and all works well now.

Comment: @GaTechThomas The Bluetooth in question is a Qualcomm Atheros. What is particularly troubling about this is that it worked flawlessly in Windows 7 the entire time I've had it, so I'm tending towards blaming the driver/Win8 incompatibility instead of the hardware.

Comment: I would not be at all surprised if it's drivers as well for my problem with Dell's Bluetooth.